# Intellisense for PHP in Coda

Tags: php, intellisense, coda

I was wondering if there is a plugin or feature in Coda to have intellisense for you own-defined php functions, while coding?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one that will highlight custom functions -- in any language. It doesn't have the capabilities that Dreamweaver does with regards to code prediction. Maybe that's a version 2.0 feature. If there is a plugin, I've never seen it but that's not saying much!  :)